# How can I get Regex_replace to match a special character in Ansible, and append a \ in front of it?

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to create a regex that matches any special characters inside of a URL, and then adds the escape character \  in front of it.  I have created the following regex, which correctly captures the right characters from the string, but it does not add the \ in front of the special characters.

`For example - test-google.com would look like test\-google\.com`

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    site: "test-google.com"
    site2: "test.mywebsite.com"

  tasks:
   - name: Bad at regex
     debug: 
        msg: "{{ site | regex_replace('[^\\w]', '[^\\\w]') }}"

     register: regex

   - debug:
        msg: "{{ regex }}"
```

I have tried `'[^\\'\'w]'` as well as `'\w'`

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either

```
msg: "{{ site | regex_replace(r'\W', r'\\\g<0>') }}"
```

or

```
msg: "{{ site | regex_replace('\\W', '\\\\\\g<0>') }}"
```

Here, `\W` matches any non-word char, and the replacement string contains a `\` (expressed with 4 backslashes in the regular, non-raw, string literal, and 
2 backslashes in a raw string literal) and then the whole match value expressed with the replacement backreference `\g<0>`.

Comment: This mostly works, thanks!  One caveat - when it is doing the replacement, it is appending two /'s instead of just one.  Example - `test\\-google\\.com`

Comment: @J.Doe: Probably, it is related to the way the strings are viewed. In the Python environment, [these two lines of code output just 1 backslash](https://ideone.com/nEGEhL).

Comment: Yep pretty much.  It looks like, per - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10067, that it is due to the way debug prints the output.  It has to escape the /, so it shows up as //.  It's actually only one /.